# Merge two array with index in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I have code like this

```
 foreach($tests as $test){
         if($test=='true') {
                $temp[]['name']='a';
                $temp[]['child']='b';
             }
            else{
                $temp[]['name']='c';
                $temp[]['child']='d';
            }
        }
 prtint_r($temp);
```

Result is :

> [{"name":"c"},{"child":"d"},{"name":"c"},{"child":"d"},{"name":"a"},{"child":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"child":"d"}]

But I want this result :

> [[{"name":"c"},{"child":"d"}],[{"name":"c"},{"child":"d"}],[{"name":"a"},{"child":"b"}],[{"name":"c"},{"child":"d"}]]

Comment: post your array `$tests`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add array instead of both items at once

```
foreach($tests as $test){
     if($test=='true') {
            $temp[] = ['name'=>'a', 'child'='b'];
         }
        else{
            $temp[] = ['name' => 'c', 'child'='d'];
        }
    }
prtint_r($temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

reuse your `$tests` key to get same key when assign value...

```
foreach($tests as $k=>$test){
     if($test=='true') {
            $temp[$k]['name']='a';
            $temp[$k]['child']='b';
         }
        else{
            $temp[$k]['name']='c';
            $temp[$k]['child']='d';
        }
    }
    var_dump($temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quiet simple, each time php reads `$array[]` it reads it as a new array key,

```
$array[] = 1; //Key 0
$array[] = 2; //Key 1
$array[] = 3; //Key 2
$array[] = 4; //Key 3
```

To assign / control the key you can use multiple methods, one of the simpler ones are like so.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $value){
    $array[$i]['name'] = 'Jamie'; 
    $array[$i]['age'] = 1;

    $i++;
}
```

Each time the foreach loop runs the `$i` variable will increase and assign your array a new key on each run through.

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
       [name] => Jamie
       [age] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array(
       [name] => Jamie
       [age] => 1
    )   
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($tests as $test) {
  if ($test == 'true') {
    $temp[$i] = array('name' => 'a', 'child'='b');
  } else {
    $temp[$i] = array('name' => 'c', 'child'='d');
  }
  $i++;
}
prtint_r($temp);
```